# PHP - File Upload Fail

Tags: php, file, upload, permissions

I don't understand why this is not working. It should be very easy.

upload.php :

```
$uploaddir = '/usr/share/nginx/www/pitfax/upload/'; 
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo "<p>";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {   
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n"; 
} 
else {
    echo "Upload failed"; 
}

echo "</p>"; 
echo '<pre>'; 
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:'; 
print_r($_FILES); print "</pre>";
```

form page:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

the **error** output is :

```
Upload failed

Here is some more debugging info:Array (
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => test.pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phptM0p4w
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 1287464
        )

)
```

- Webserver : NginX
- Permissions for `upload.php` : 644
- Permissions for `upload` directory : 755
- Working in SSH with root user.
- **Edit :** upload_max_filesize = 2M
- **Edit :** post_max_size = 8M

Another thing! After upload is done, I want to get absolute path of the uploaded file. (ex:`/usr/share/nginx/www/pitfax/upload/test.pdf`)

Comment: Have you tried setting the upload directory to 777?

Comment: @LukePittman Yes it didn't worked.

Comment: @zerkms What error log are you referring to ?

Comment: Are you confident that basename() isn't effecting it?  In your debug output perhaps you can `echo $uploadfile;` and just double check that its not just trying to upload as a directory.

Comment: @LukePittman the output of `echo $uploadfile;` is `upload/test.pdf`

Comment: What's the value for `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in your php.ini (or equivalent)?

Comment: How can `$uploadfile` be only `upload/test.pdf`? There should be a full path there! If there is no upload directory at the place where the script is executing, that would explain while `move_uploaded_file` fails.

Comment: Agreed, see my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value of $uploadfile is **upload/test.pdf** but you want it to be **/usr/share/nginx/www/pitfax/upload/test.pdf** than I would suspect that would be your problem.

Try this code:

```
$uploadfile = '/usr/share/nginx/www/pitfax/upload/' . $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
  echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
  print_r ($_FILES);
}
```

**EDIT:** Code formatting.

Comment: Ok the output of `echo $uploadfile;` is as it should be. But the upload still fails. output is `Array ( [userfile] => Array ( [name] => test.pdf [type] => application/pdf [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpbGRbCg [error] => 0 [size] => 1287464 ) )`

Comment: When trying to help someone else with a problem I was told this isn't a debugging service.  So I'm afraid at this point there isn't much I can do.  I would check log files (apache error logs) for hints, echo all of your variables, try with fixed file names, etc...

Comment: I changed permission of upload directory to 777 again and suddenly the upload worked! Thanks!